# Omp Amp Design for shifting a voltage range

Tags: operational-amplifier, dac

My DAC can only output voltages between 0-5 V and I want to linearly shift the range to -2.5 to 2.5 V. For example, a 2.5 input would (ideally) lead to a zero volt output. Likewise, a 5 V input would lead to a 2.5 V output. What circuit would be ideal for this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is to reverse your 0V-5V to 5V-0V in firmware and use a subtracting circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fO9aEC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Optionally, add another inverting amplifier afterward to get -2.5V to +2.5V for 0-5V in.

The reference and resistor accuracy, and op-amp type will depend on your required precision. The op-amps will require a dual supply such as +/-5V, of course.

Comment: Is that Vref + or -? If +, doesn't it add current into the node along with the 0-5 V source, making the opamp have still more current to pull? For some reason, I imagined removing some current instead.

Comment: @jonk, you're right it has to be negative (to oppose the DAC). If OP wants to use a positive reference, it can be added into the 2nd op-amp instead. If the precision required is moderate (0.1% resistors or worse) then this is pretty cheap- a dual op-amp and a 2.5V series or shunt reference.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a -5V supply that can be relied on, you can use two resistors (such as 10k and 20k) for changing the 0 to 5V signal into a -1.667 to +1.667 signal. The two resistors just form a potential divider. That gives you a bipolar signal and all that remains is to amplify this by 1.5 using a non-inverting op-amp configuration: -

[image]

So R1 will be (say) 10k and R2 will be 20k. I've chosen resistor values that match the original uni to bipolar potential divider.

Answer (score 1):

I think this answer is simpler: Do the inversion and scaling with a single-opamp by using a differential amplifier configuration.

See the LTSpice sim below. I picked R = 100k randomly. Use a lower value if your opamp has significant input bias current to reduce any error.

The gain of a diff amp is simply the feedback resistor / the input resistor. In your case you want GAIN = (-2.5V - 2.5V) / (0 - 5V) = 1, so feedback and input resistors need to be the same value.

Because you're only driving the + side of the diff amp, the - side needs to be referenced to 1/2 of the input voltage swing. Your DAC outputs 0 to 5V so halfway is 2.5 Volts. So basically you drive the + input with the DAC and you tie the - input to 2.5V through a 100k resistor.

But instead of a separate 2.5V reference, you can simply use the Thevenin equivalent: two 200k resistors as a voltage divider to 5V. Thus the negative input sees this as 100k at 2.5 Volts.

On the output side of the diff amp, you would bias R4 to a voltage that is halfway of your output swing. Your output range is -2.5V to 2.5V and the halfway point is 0 Volts, so R4 gets tied to GND.

The diff amp is a nice configuration for doing just this: converting one input range to a different output range with whatever gain, offset and polarity you want.

There's a nice writeup of how a diff amp configuration works at:
http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/opamp/opamp_5.html

[image]